# Call javascript library from native ios app

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, rsa

I have to use this library for RSA encryption and so far, I really cannot find any similar library for iOS app. Is there any library that I can use?

https://github.com/wwwtyro/cryptico/

As a result, I am going to invoke javascript method from native code and write like this.

```
NSString *jsPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cryptico" ofType:@"js"];

NSString *scriptString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:jsPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

JSContext *context = [[JSContext alloc] init];
context = [[JSContext alloc] init];
[context evaluateScript:scriptString];
JSValue *function = context[@"generateRSAKey"];

JSValue* result = [function callWithArguments:@[@"Hello", @1024]]; //pass the string whatever you want.
[result toString]; // This will give the value in string format.
```

It is also not okay. I try to put that in UIWebview and call also.

```
NSString *jsFile = @"cryptico.js";
NSString *jsFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:jsFile ofType:nil];
NSURL *jsURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:jsFilePath];
NSString *javascriptCode = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:jsURL.path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascriptCode];

NSString *functionCall = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"generateRSAKey(%@,%@)", @"Hello", @1024];
NSString *resultStr = [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:functionCall];


NSLog(@"resultStr = %@", resultStr);
```

The javascript method in that file is this one. I need to call this method and pass parameter.

```
// Generates an RSA key from a passphrase.
my.generateRSAKey = function(passphrase, bitlength)
{
    Math.seedrandom(sha256.hex(passphrase));
    var rsa = new RSAKey();
    rsa.generate(bitlength, "03");
    return rsa;
}
```

But still, it doesn't give me anything. How shall I do?

**Edit**

I try to invoke like this too and it give "undefined".

```
JSValue *test = context[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cryptico.generateRSAKey(%@,%@)", @"Hello", @1024]];
```

I need to understand what/how they are generating.

Public key from Swift Library (https://github.com/soyersoyer/SwCrypt)

> -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCYPmwHqTcZf9vaeI2ENAsjbjNO
>   nLzJJyhIzs9xZKXZpE+t4gKYbJgt+Pjo+EGDHFGbfC3FcYK/qlfVRDvDGHTAWZfI
>   kudzz+XXiQSlktod9CzHXaeDz5RhTPTaWEIkAUIRiKyoFddeaAOsuZhXxzv6sTah
>   VFgSIbDnx0gM6wuBRwIDAQAB
>   -----END PUBLIC KEY-----

Public key from ionic library

> uXjrkGqe5WuS7zsTg6Z9DuS8cXLFz38ue+xrFzxrcQJCXtVccCoUFP2qH/AQ
>   4qMvxxvqkSYBpRm1R5a4/NdQ5ei8sE8gfZEq7dlcR+gOSv3nnS4/CX1n5Z5m
>   8bvFPF0lSZnYQ23xlyjXTaNacmV0IuZbqWd4j9LfdAKq5dvDaoE=

Comment: There is exists a lot of Obj-C libraries to encrypt data by RSA. Why do you want to use this strange JS-way? Ex.: https://github.com/ideawu/Objective-C-RSA

Comment: Yes. I saw really a lot of library. Problem is that we have hybrid ionic app and backend. Both are using that library. Now, I need to re-write everything in native iOS code and server will still be the same. How shall I do?

Comment: So, by the task you MUST use native library, I guess :) RSA is a standart protocol and you shouldn't have any problems to change JS library on native library.

Comment: yes. problem is I can't find native library which is same as that javascript  library.  That javascript  library use passphrase and give public key. I use this library but public key format is quite different. https://github.com/soyersoyer/SwCrypt

Comment: Can you give examples of key generated by both libs on one passphrase?

Comment: Hi @Zaakk I have updated to show key.

Comment: These keys are result for "I Love @Live!" passphraze?

Comment: no. It is example only. Public key will always be different.